# How to understand the first 'that'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Graham King. (2000). Good Punctuation. p.135.

> A final example, from The Sunday Times(22/5/94):
>
> If I had the slightest interest in making my biography of Kenneth
> Branagh and Emma Thompson a work of speculative salaciousness, I could
> do worse than model my approach on Stuart Wavell's.
>
> It's fairly clear **that** by referring to the preceding text **that** it is
> Wavells biographical approach **that** is being deprecated here.

How to interpret the first 'that'?

If removing the first 'that',it is also proper:
"It's fairly clear by referring to the preceding text **that** it is
Wavells biographical approach **that** is being deprecated here."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many *thats* here, in my opinion, and the first one should go. "by referring to the preceding text" is an adverbial phrase modifying "It's fairly clear" and could be moved to the start of the sentence. But if you do that you get the nonsensical:

> By referring to the preceding text, it's fairly clear **that** that it is Wavells biographical approach that is being deprecated here.

It's a natural mistake to make - there is often a "that" after "It's clear...", but if you include an adverbial phrase, then "that" should come after the adverbial phrase, and particularly should not be repeated.

(There is more latitude about where to place an adverbial phrase if you put it in parentheses/commas and clearly set it off from the rest of the sentence, but I don't really like "it's fairly clear that, by referring to the preceding text, it is Wavell's biographical approach that is being deprecated here." Because it's not Wavell's approach that is referring to the preceding text, it's the clarity of the judgment. And still one less "that".)

To take a shorter, simpler example, if you want to add "to me" instead of "by referring to the preceding text" you would write "It's clear to me that it is Wavell's approach..." not "It's clear that to me that it is Wavell's approach..."

Comment: Swapping in ***to me*** instead of ***by referring to the preceding text*** provides Incisive clarification. The cited original is so convoluted it's difficult to see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 1):

> *It's fairly clear* [***that** by referring to the preceding text that it is*
> *Wavells biographical approach that is being deprecated here*].

The first "that" is a subordinator, a meaningless marker introducing the bracketed declarative content clause functioning as complement of the adjective phrase "fairly clear".

"That" is optional here, but preferred.

(From my comment below to the OP: "The second "that" is not required".)

Comment: How to take the second 'that'? Does it introduce an appositive: 'It is Wavells biographical approach that is being deprecated here'?

Comment: @WingledTiger The second "that" is not required.

Comment: Why? What is the constituent of 'It is Wavells biographical approach that is being deprecated here',an appositive?

Comment: @WingledTiger No: appositives are noun phrases.  The sentence is _It's fairly clear that [by referring to the preceding text] it is Wavells biographical approach that is being deprecated here_. The bracketed bit is an optional means adjunct.

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot.